# Is it possible to execute multiple explains in one query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, explain

is it possible to have more than 1 explains in one single query

eg. something like

```
(EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tablea) UNION (EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tableb)
```

such that this one single query returns explain results of 2 queries instead of just one

Comment: Why would someone want to do this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: [@Mike Brant] - to save queries being executed to db if I have over 100 queries that I want to EXPLAIN

Comment: No, don't this is if you want to `EXPLAIN` 100 queries. Explain each one by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh no. You can do;

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tablea UNION SELECT * FROM tableb
```